# pam_mount changes owner of mountpoint to root

Tags: mount, security, pam

On Debian 8.3 I want to mount an encrypted container `/usr/local/share/test.img` with pam_mount at login at the mountpoint `/home/test` (which is owned by `test`, of course). The LUKS encrypted disk image `test.img` has the same password as the login password of the user `test`.

This is my `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pam_mount SYSTEM "pam_mount.conf.xml.dtd">
<pam_mount>
<debug enable="0" />

<volume user="test" fstype="crypt" path="/usr/local/share/test.img" mount="/home/test" />
<mntoptions allow="nosuid,nodev,loop,encryption,fsck,nonempty,allow_root,allow_other" />
<mntoptions require="nosuid,nodev" />
<logout wait="0" hup="0" term="0" kill="0" />
<mkmountpoint enable="1" remove="true" />
<cryptmount>mount.crypt %(VOLUME) %(MNTPT)</cryptmount>
<cryptumount>umount.crypt %(MNTPT)</cryptumount>
</pam_mount>
```

Strangely, I had to add to `/etc/fstab` the line:

```
/usr/local/share/test.img /home/test crypt   user,noauto     0       0
```

Otherwise pam_mount complains that it can't find it in fstab!?

It works as it should except one problem: `/home/test` becomes owned by `root` and is not writable by the user `test`!

Adding `noroot="1"` doesn't work, too, pam_mount the  complains that it can't set up the loopback device for the encrypted container.

How do I mount `/home/test` with pam_mount so that it is owned by `test`?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the last line in `/etc/fstab` to:

```
/usr/local/share/test.img /home/test crypt   user,noauto,uid=1000     0       0
```

1000 is the uid of the user `test`.

And added `uid` to the allowed options in `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml`:

```
<mntoptions allow="nosuid,uid,nodev,loop,encryption,fsck,nonempty,allow_root,allow_other" />
```

Now it works. But it's not clear to me why.